# Is there a way to expose ports when the three default firewalls were disabled

Tags: freebsd

I think I disabled the three firewalls that come with FreeBSD (just for experimentation purposes). I checked the modules that load with the kernel (using "kldstat"). The only modules that load are: kernel --> ng_socket.ko, netgraph.ko, ng_mppc.ko and rc4.ko). I'd like to know what module is still blocking my ports now. After removing all firewall options from the rc.file and re-compiling the kernel without the pf option (or any firewall for that matter), I can't still open ports freely. How does it work exactly? Thanks.

Comment: The FreeBSD firewalls are not enabled by default (as you can see in `/etc/defaults/rc.conf`). You do not specifiy which ports you are trying to use and how. But be aware that port numbers <1024 are proviliged; only the root user can access them. An ordinary user cannot `bind()` to them. Can you provide som examples of the errors that you get?

Comment: @RolandSmith, thank you very much for taking the time to give me some feedback. The problem I was having was when trying to set up a VPN (IPSec) server in FreeBSD -following a tutorial I found on the FreeBSD official forum. I disabled all the three firewalls that come with FreeBSD (pf, ipfilter and ipfw) I wasn't able to connect to any UDP ports. I decided to erase all the packages installed from the src(ipsec-tools, mpd5) and try a different approach. I'm still looking for a clear/concise way of setting up a professional VPN solution in FreeBSD. What is your experience with VPN under FreeBSD?

Comment: Nactus, personally I haven't had the need to set up a VPN yet. So I have no experience with it. The instructions in the [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ipsec.html) look pretty straightforward, though. You should edit your question, describing the steps that you followed and what the result was. Did you manage to compile and install the custom kernel that you need? Keep in mind that the handbook _assumes_ that both networks have a gateway that's running FreeBSD.